# How to allow all arabic characters to be shown on UITextVIew?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, textview

if i have this arabic text: "لِلَّهِ" it looks very weird only Apple devices.

[image: c]

but if i paste the same exact text for example in a google chrome textfield it shows this (which is correct):

[image]

What can i do so my `UITextView` allows all characters regardless of which language/word it is?

Answer (score 2):

You can always download any font you like and just import it into your app. To do that upload .ttf files to project > register fonts in Info.plist file ("Fonts provided by application")

I always use googleFonts to find suitable font for me

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the font to an arabic font style you can download on the web.